# PHP server for Android turn based multiplayer game?

Tags: php, android

I developed a turn based game for Android, and now I want to add multiplayer gaming. I don't want to use providers like "skiller", I would like to develop my own server.

I don't have a dedicated server, but I have a php hosting with "1 and 1". Would be a good idea to use this hosting like a game server? My idea is that my Android game polls server every X seconds waiting for opponent move.

What do you think about it?

Comment: Are you doing using socket connection ?

Comment: I don't use socket connection because I readed that it would be a lot of charge for a shared hosting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked into using them for hosting and I have heard great things about their support. BUT unless your using a dedicated server that they offer (instead of the base level shared hosting service) you probably won't have the resources available to support a gaming server.

If you can handle doing the server config yourself or are good with detailed instructions on how to set one up then I highly recommend using the $20 a month linode.com base plan. I am using it for site hosting and it makes a huge difference in terms of performance and flexibility. Also I have seen some performance benchmark comparisons done between it, slicehost, rackspace, and Amazon S3 and it blew all of them (especially Amazon) out of the water. The benchmark is 2 or 3 years old, but it is still rather telling.

Linode will let you do ANYTHING you want within the bounds of the law with the server. So if you want to host an adult site they won't have a problem with it. They will probably have a problem with setting up a spam server or some shady things like that. But they are cool with everything else it seems. Plus they are probably the most affordable option out there.

I would add that you may look into the technology behind APE servers (AJAX Push Engine). Its a high efficiency chat system that works with pretty much any server-end language and front-end.

http://www.ape-project.org/

Comment: In internet, a 2 or 3 years old benchmark is worth nothing. If you are affiliated with linode you have to state it according to the rules. However, Rackspace is by far the best hoster I had, but pricey. Amazon is the most flexible one.

Comment: I am not affiliated with Linode in any way, shape, or form. That said I am a new customer (been with them for about 4 months). So I have bias based on experience with them AND with the Amazon network (which kinda sucks in my experience, which is as recent as today). Much of my knowledge of Slicehost is anecdotal at best. While I agree that a 2 or 3 year old benchmark tells little to nothing of the current establishment it does give knowledge of their history and thus relative potential.

Comment: I should also add that I do have experience with Rackspace at work and they are fantastic and amazing. Both in their support and the service they offer. I have nothing negative to say about them in general. That said Linode currently has the most affordable and understandable pricing setup of all the cloud-based hosts I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I would do it, since your game is asking the server for pull request lets skip one step. Thats asking the MySQL server. So here is the way I would do it.

From what it sounds like its a html5 game meaning that you could set cookies, on the users phone. I would have a cookie or even a javascript var that then stores a JSON or ARRAY string. from this you would be able to push 1 or 0 to the PHP script that hopefully would be able to send it to the user or store it as a .txt files it is known that fetching data from mysql is slower and if you have 400 users all doing it at 5second intervals you will bring down most shared servers, They are just not strong enough to do what you want.

If your budget is small may I suggest you look this option. I cant really think of away you can do this without storing the data somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should not listen to programming language specific arguments, most of the time they are personal preferences. What you want to do is of course possible with PHP. You can do good and bad programming in every language. For a turn based game PHP is totally sufficient, if you know how to use it. Use the programming language you are most comfortable with, and you will be just fine.

What is more important: You want your game to be successful, 1und1 is **not** capable of handling a way of "success", because of its localized and not scalable on demand nature. If you want to gain money or spread, you really should not fear to invest some *low* bucks and go for Amazons infrastructure. You will have to learn a little, but it is definitely worth it.

Most IDEs (Zend Studio, PHP Storm, ...) even have good integration already. A shared hoster or a localized storage hoster is not what you want, because if your app gets famous they simply will not be able to handle global demand. And you will have security problems. If you *really* expect your game to be successful, even a VPS will reach its limit almost immediately.

You can try to grow your game by using 1und1 first, and upon demand going to a better solution. But quite some games just died because the demand was much higher than expected. The worst thing about this is you have to think less euphoric but more realistic.

To sum it up: Just use the language you are most comfortable with, if you believe in your idea do not fear to invest little bucks to meet the global market, create your own protocol with as less data transfer as possible, and please poll more often than "x seconds", because a second waiting for the opponent feels like three days. And you are on your way.

Good progress! And post a link when you're done:)

Comment: Oh, and "AJAX polling" in the answers of course just describes a technique, not the language on the server.

Comment: I'm not limited to PHP, I wanted to use PHP because I've a shared hosting and I thought I can use it as game server. But if it can't handle all user requests, I won't use 1and1 shared host for that.

So, not being limited to any language? And working with a low budget... what can I use? Amazon server would be a good choice?

Comment: As I said in my response above, Linode.com offers probably the most affordable service and is completely customizable. I know I am beating a dead horse with a stick right now. But at $20 a month for a virtual cloud server instance (which is what both Amazon and Rackspace offer, though with different levels of support and computing power) you really can't beat it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a loot at Linode.com, Amazon and Rackspace

Answer (score -1):

You can use Firebase messaging service to implement the same. Further you have must one Web server (e.g. PHP).

1. Use your android code to send request to PHP file at web server.
2. From this web server you can send broadcast message in form of firebase Messaging which will deliver to all devices of your subscribed topic.
3. All android device those listen for this FCM can respond(depend on parameters set by your code).